# can't create view in bookshelf knex. getting migration error as: schema.createView is not a function

Tags: node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I wish to create view that collectively shows data from multiple tables in my mysql database. Project is nodeJS based.

npm versions using "bookshelf": "^0.14.2" & "knex": "^0.17.6".
migration failed with error: knex.schema.createView is not a function.

migration file content are as follows:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    
  return knex.schema.createView('sp_form_view', function(view) {
    view.columns(['first_name']);
    view.as(knex('sp_form').select('first_name').where('id','>', 20));
  });

};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropView('sp_form_view');
};
```

I tried creation of view using migration command as knex migrate:latest. I got error as createView is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

View support wasn't added to Knex until version **0.95.12** (https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#09512---28-october-2021)

If you are not able to update your knex version you'll need to use `knex.raw`